# With RequireJS optimization, are templates added to the build file or stay "on demand"?

Tags: optimization, requirejs, requirejs-optimizer, requirejs-text

Using RequireJS, after optimization using `r.js` are files loaded via the text plugin (like templates) downloaded on demand or included in the single optimized build file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the value of the [`inlineText` optimizer option](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/2.1.14/build/example.build.js#L235-237). By default it's set to `true`, meaning that all `text!` resources will be resolved and embedded into the final bundle at build time. If you'd prefer loading it at runtime set it to `false`.